# Vampire and Werewolf at the same time, cannot remove

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm an argonian and and a werewolf so I should have 150% resistance to disease, but somehow, suddenly, my screen keeps turning red every five seconds telling me that my vampiric powers recede as I feed. I check my effects menu and I maintain the traits or a level 1 vampire. I may have gotten caught in Serana's vampire spell, but now I'm a vampire and cannot seem to get rid of it. I looked up console command and used it, but to no effect. I still possess the beast form power. I've attempted to activate beast form, but that did nothing, my character's eyes have not changed color, and nobody says anything about it. I tried talking to inn keepers and the dawnguard, but nothing is activating the quest for a cure, nor does talking to Falion. I really do not want to be a vampire.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't be both at the same time, can you? Did you use any console commands or were you able to become both without the use of the console or mods?

Comment: Nope. I've read it's a glitch or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following console command:

```
player.removespell 000b8780
```

Source: [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKh7goH3ImU). If the command itself does not work, try to look at the links in the video description.

Comment: It says I don't have it. I also tried adding it then removing it, but that also didn't work.

Comment: You can try removing the werewolf-status first, then adding/removing vampirism, then adding werewolf status agagin.

Comment: I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I tried changing race, sex change, but then I got Serana to make a vampire lord, then I did the quest to get cured.